# java double to BigDecimal convertion adding extra trailing zero

Tags: double, bigdecimal

```
double d =0.0000001;
BigDecimal d1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(d);
System.out.println(d1.toPlainString());
```

prints output => `0.00000010` i am expecting `0.0000001`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to get a precise `BigDecimal` value, avoid using a `float` or `double` to initialize it. The **conversion from text to floating point type** is by definition not guaranteed to be precise. The conversion from such a type to `BigDecimal` is precise, but may not exactly yield the result you expected.

If you can avoid using a `double` or `float` for initialization, then do something like this instead:

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("0.0000001");
```

This will already give you the desired output, because the conversion from (decimal) text to `BigDecimal` is precise.

But if you really **must** convert from a `double`, then try:

```
double d = 0.0000001;
BigDecimal d1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(d);
System.out.println(d1.stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString());
```

This will strip (remove) any trailing zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `DecimalFormat` to format your `BigDecimal`.

```
double d = 0.0000001;
BigDecimal d1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(d);
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.0000000");
System.out.println(df.format(d1));
```

Comment: But how do i get the scale (ie.#0.0000000) form double value, it is dynamic, and if decimal fraction goes >5 in that case it will converted into exponential